# LinqToSQL Union casting error when selecting multiple columns (Unable to cast DataQuery of... to IEnumerable of...)

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, union

I had a run-time error when the following code was executed: (vb.net)

```
dim q = (From x in db.T1
         select x.F11, x.F12).Union( _
        (From y in db.T2
         select y.F21, y.F22)
```

F11 and F21 have the same type; F21 and F22 have the same type.

The runtime error stated "Unable to cast from DataQuery(of anonymous type(...) to iEnumerable (of anonymous type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Union` on anonymous types should work. Compiler is intelligent enough to treat  two anonymous types are same. Double check your field types in database of tow tables they should be exactly same

You can try union on same table to see this

```
(From x in db.T1
         select FIRST=x.F11, SECOND=x.F21).Union( _
        (From y in db.T1
         select FIRST=y.F11, SECOND=y.F21)
```

Comment: you shouldn't get any exception if data type on two tables are same. Have you tried on same table as i wrote in answer.do you still get exception

Comment: The exact exception: Unable to cast object of type     'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_14`2[System.String,System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[VB$AnonymousType_13`2[System.String,System.String]]'.

Comment: what is the return type of your method in which query is written

Comment: Tassadaque, your example works fine, and when changing to different table WITH SAME types, the run-time error was still generated. So I found that the field names must also be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I now understand that using **Anonymous** type **IS** allowed in **Union**.
 - You only need to make sure the field *NAMEs* **and** *TYPEs* are the same in the unioned queries, as in the example:

```
dim q = (From x in db.T1
         Select FIRST = x.F11, LAST = x.F12).Union _
        (From y in db.T2
         Select FIRST = y.F21, LAST = y.F22)
```

and F11 and F21 are of the same type; F12, F22 are of the same type

Comment: make this answer as comment and if your problem is resolved mark the above  answer as accepted